# "Agreeing" orthogonal projections

Tags: linear-algebra, projection, projection-matrices

This is a projection excercise I'm stuck on.
Lets say we have two planes in R3, $A$ and $B$, which both go through the origin. We also have two orthogonal projections, $ProjA$ and $ProjB$, projecting on plane $A$ and $B$ respectively. $ProjA$ is given by the projection matrix $P1$, so that $$ProjA(v) = P1v$$ $ProjB$ is specified by the following vector $d2$ = [knownx; d; known z] that is parallel to the projection direction.
Note that $d2$ is parametric in $d$. The matrix $P1$ and the known $x$ and $z$ values in $d2$ are given in the task.

The task is is to find the only possible value of $d$ such that the following holds for all $v ∈ R3: ProjA(ProjB(v)) = ProjB(ProjA(v))$.

My thought process was this:

Since d2 is parallell to projection direction, then d2 is orthogonal to plane B. So,

$$ProjB(v) = v - Projd2(v)$$

where $Projd2(v)$ is the projection of v onto d2: $d2.v\over||d2||^2$$d2$

Continuing,

$$ProjA(ProjB(v)) = ProjA(v-Projd2(v)) = P1(v-Projd2(v))$$

$$ProjB(ProjA(v)) = ProjB(P1v) = P1v - Projd2(P1v)$$

Thus,

$$P1(v-Projd2(v)) = P1v - Projd2(P1v)$$

And finally,

$$P1(Projd2(v)) = Projd2(P1v) $$

Am I on the right path here?

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to math.se! You should take a look at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for some tips on how to better format your text to make the equations easier to read. Cheers

Comment: Approach the problem geometrically. First you project onto one plane, then the other. Now you do it in the reverse order. When will those be the same? See if you can sketch the answer then try to work into a formal proof.

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ is the unit normal vector to plane $A$ and $b$ is the unit normal vector to plane $B$.  Then

$\text{ Proj_A } (v) = ( I_3 - {aa}^T ) v $

And similarly,

$ \text{ Proj_B }(v) = (I_3 - {bb}^T ) v $

Now using the basis $ a, b, a \times b$, we can write

$ v = c_1 a + c_2 b + c_3 (a \times b) $

So that

$ \text{ Proj_A } (v) = ( I_3 - {aa}^T ) v = v - c_1 a - c_2 a (a^T b) $

$ \text{ Proj_B } (v) = ( I_3 - {bb}^T ) v = v - c_1 b (a^T b) - c_2 b$

And

$ \text{ Proj_B }( \text{ Proj_A }) (v) = (I - {bb}^T)  ( v - c_1 a - c_2 a (a^T b) ) \\
= v - c_1 b (a^T b ) - c_2 b - (I - {bb}^T) ( c_1 a + c_2 a (a^T b) ) \\ = v - c_1 b (a^T b) - c_2 b - c_1 a - c_2 a (a^T b) + c_1 b (a^T b) + c_2 b (a^T b)^2 $

Exchanging $a$ and $b$, and $c_1$ and $c_2$, we get

$  \text{ Proj_A }( \text{ Proj_B }) (v) = v - c_2 a (a^T b) - c_1 a - c_2 b - c_1 b (a^T b) + c_2 a (a^T b) + c_1 a (a^T b)^2 $

Since $a,b$ are linearly independent, (otherwise we have the trivial case $a= \pm b$), then the equality of the two expressions implies by equating coefficients of $a$ and $b$:

$ - c_1 - c_2 (a^T b) = - c_2 (a^T b) - c1 + c_2 (a^T b) + c_1 (a^T b)^2 $

which reduces to

$ c_2 (a^T b) + c_1 (a^T b)^2 = 0 \hspace{20pt} \cdots (1)$

And similarly from the coefficients of $b$, we get

$ - c_1 (a^T b) - c_2 + c_1 (a^T b) + c_2 (a^T b)^2 = - c_2 - c_1 (a^T b) $

which reduces to

$ c_1 (a^T b) + c_2 (a^T b)^2 = 0 \hspace{20pt} \cdots (2)$

Since $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary, then equations (1) and (2) can only be satisfied if $a^T b = 0 $ , i.e. the two planes $A$ and $B$ are perpendicular to each other.

Therefore, from the given matrix $P_1 = I - {aa}^T$ , we have $Q = {a a}^T = I - P_1 $

From $Q = I - P_1$ we can compute the ratios $\alpha = a_2/a_1 = Q_{21}/Q_{11} $ and $\beta=a_3/a_1 = Q_{31}/Q_{11}$ , then we will $ a = t [ 1, \alpha, \beta]$, and since $a^T a = 1$ we find $t$, and hence we now have $a$.

Since $ b = [x_0, d , z_0 ] $ , then we want

$ a_1 x_0 + a_2 d + a_3 z_0 = 0 $

From which $d$ follows.